# C# compiler optimizations for benchmarking purposes

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, profiling, benchmarking

I needed to check performance of some .NET API, and I came up with this code.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int res = (int) SOME .NET FUNCTION TO RUN;
}
sw.Stop();
double time = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

On my second thought, I was afraid that the compiler optimizes out all the operation as the `res` is not used any where. And I modified the code as follows.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
long sumIt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int res = (int) SOME .NET FUNCTION TO RUN;
    sumIt += res;
}
sw.Stop();
double time = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
value = (int) sumIt / 1000;
```

Interestingly, it doesn't seem that the compiler doesn't optimize out the operation with my first example. I tested with csc (Visual Studio), and mono.

Here comes my questions.

- Is it safe to make a benchmark as my first example?
- Isn't C# compiler smart enough to understand that some of the code can be optimized out? Or, is there any compiler parameter for that?

### ADDED

The `SOME FUNCTION TO RUN` is actually `SOME .NET FUNCTION TO RUN`, and I modified the OP.
And based on the answers, it looks like that the C# compiler cannot(or doesn't) optimize the operation as the `.NET FUNCTION TO RUN` might have the side effect.

Comment: What if SOMEFUNCION has side-effects? That fact you don't use its return value doesn't mean it can be thrown away. In theory the compiler could analyze the function (and any functions in that function, ...) but I don't think that's practical and I don't think it does.

Comment: I was wondering about this when I wrote some benchmarks in the past, too. I have not come across a conclusive statement, but it seems the compiler will not optimize away any calls to methods (that also includes property getters, btw) residing in another asssembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler (JIT) may optimize whole function call out if it finds out that it has no side effects. It likely need to be able to inline function to detect that.

I tried small function that only acts on input arguments and see it is optimized out by checking resulting assembly (make sure to try Release build with "Suppres optimization on module load" unchecked).

```
 ...
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
 {    
    int res = (int) Func(i);
 }
 ...

 static int Func(int arg1)
 {
    return arg1 * arg1;
 }
```

Disassembly:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    00000016  xor         eax,eax 
    00000018  inc         eax 
    00000019  cmp         eax,3E8h 
    0000001e  jl          00000018 
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like that if the function inside a loop has any kind of functions that cannot be inlined. C# compiler cannot optimize the code out. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know. In theory JIT (not C# compiler) may be able to do that with regular functions too - only someone from JIT team will be able to give you definitive answer.

Comment: @prossek I'm no expert with the C# compiler, but for Hotspot the answer is yes. The vast majority of optimizations don't work across method boundaries (one reason why aggressive inlining is of such importance for the JIT) - or more exactly they could implement this, but it's not worth the additional complexity and cost. Basically the JIT would have to make sure across all possible code paths that there's no observable side effect from the function which is non trivial even if all the code can be inlined.